# Pakistani CNIC and mobile format Masking Required

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have work on a project to used the mask of cnic and mobile for Pakistani format.

The format of CNIC is : XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X

The format of Mobile is 03XX-XXXXXXX

CODE:

```
   $('#CNIC_No').mask("99999-9999999-9");
```

Comment: Need to understand what ```#CNIC_No``` contains, and what mask actually does. Can you be more detailed with your question and provide more explanation?

Comment: This question has been closed but i am posting just because of future purposes
I find the solution through Regex
``var idToTest = '12345-1234567-1',
myRegExp = new RegExp(/\d{5}-\d{7}-\d/);

if(myRegExp.test(idToTest)) {
    //if true
}
else {
    //if false
}
``

Comment: just add this in code

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" step="1" id="contact">
<script>
$('input[type=number]').on('mouseup keyup', function () {
  $(this).val(Math.min(9999999999999, Math.max(0, $(this).val())));
});
</script>

Comment: just add this in code

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" step="1" id="contact">
<script>
$('input[type=number]').on('mouseup keyup', function () {
  $(this).val(Math.min(9999999999999, Math.max(0, $(this).val())));
});
</script>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please try this code,

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>


    <input type="text"  data-inputmask="'mask': '99999-9999999-9'"  placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X"  name="cnic" required="" >

    <input type="text"  data-inputmask="'mask': '0399-99999999'" required=""  type = "number" maxlength = "12" >

   <script>
    $(":input").inputmask();

   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

numeric keyboard instead of alphabetical:-

```
this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

in the file `MaskedEditText.java`. Now setting `android:inputType = "numeric"` will work.

Thanks

Comment: What does changing a java file have to do with it?